# A service ("doctrine.dbal.connection") can use either the old or the new factory syntax, not both

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, netbeans-7

I have a Symfony2 project, there were some added bundles lately, I tried to run the project and I got this error :

```
A service ("doctrine.dbal.connection") can use either the old or the
new factory syntax, not both.
```

This is the full stack :

```
in CheckDefinitionValidityPass.php line 54
    at CheckDefinitionValidityPass->process(object(ContainerBuilder)) in Compiler.php line 117
    at Compiler->compile(object(ContainerBuilder)) in ContainerBuilder.php line 614
    at ContainerBuilder->compile() in Kernel.php line 534
    at Kernel->initializeContainer() in Kernel.php line 128
    at Kernel->boot() in Kernel.php line 183
    at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in app_dev.php line 28
```

Anyone got a clue what could it be?

Answer (score 1):

In symfony 2.6+ the methods factory_service & factory_method were deprecated.

Please make sure that you're using a recent version of doctrine/dbal:

composer.json:

```
"require": {
    "doctrine/dbal": "~2.5"
}
```

And then run "composer update" to make sure the package gets updated properly.

Comment: I'm using Symfony2.6.4 and I did change it to  "doctrine/dbal": "~2.5" and still I have the same error.

Comment: I corrected my answer, those method were deprecated in Symfony 2.6+. Please make sure you run "composer update" to update the package.

Comment: Okay, there must be another issue as updating the package to the latest version fixed the issue for me. I hope you find a solution.